# implement a web-app for document collaboration

Tags: java, css, angularjs, document, collaboration

I would like to design a document collaboration web-app where students can share their academic documents with the instructor and instructor can comment and give grade to their work. I have explored Sharepoint and I found that it is the right solution for my requirements. However, I would like to gain hands-on knowledge of Java, HTML/CSS and other leading technologies which might need to develop Sharepoint-like application. In past, I have developed a web-app tool(CreditCardDebtViewer - https://github.com/dhanu010/dredit) for credit card management using Google REST API (using Drive and Spreadsheet API) so I am familier to Java, angularJS, HTML/CSS etc.

I have following questions -

1. What are my options if I opt to write a web-app?
2. Which technology suits better for developing such application and
   also for giving me good opportunity to learn the technology?
3. How development using google API help in document collaboration
   where instructor can access all the shared documents uploaded by
   teams (which may comprise 2-3 students)?
4. Other than Google Docs, Which API can I use to develop this
   application.

Please guide me.

Regards,
Avani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at CMS (Content Management Systems). These will have document management, versioning, permissions, workflow, etc.

There a number of popular Java based systems and two big standard: JCR (Java Content Repository) and the newer, language agnostic CMIS (Content Management Interoperability Service).

If you wanted to start with a framework and build you own, look at Apache Jackrabbit or Apache Sling.

If you were looking for something like Sharepoint, a finished product that you can extend, look at Hippo CMS or Alfresco CMS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The suggestions that you gave have technologies which are absolutely new for a beginner like me. However, I would love to explore them and start a document-collaboration web-app using your suggestions.

Comment: I have looked into Apache Sling and started understanding the concepts. I have one question however; I want to implement a web portal where I wanted to implement sharepoint-like facilities. The web portal should be capable of providing facilities like creating teams, further teams can upload documents on which an instructor can comment on and provide grades. Does development in Sling provides document-collaboration like sharepoint? This is because, everywhere I read about Sling, it is about content management and I am pretty confused whether Sling serves the document-collaboration features?

Comment: Both Apache Sling and Jackrabbit are frameworks, so they will not provide anything out of the box. You will have to code it. Sling doesn't ship with a handy UI for users, you would have to create or find one that suites your needs. Sling does provide groups, permissions, and a Resource/Node model that you can use as a backend system to create teams, manage permissions, any any type of document collaboration you want; but, you have to build it from their object model. Alfresco and Hippo have out of the box Sharepoint like solutions.

Comment: thanks a bunch, Lucas! It helped me understand the concept and work accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is a quite late answer but you can try http://swellrt.org, an open source framework to develop collaborative apps with real-time rich-text editting.

Comment: It's a great solution for tasks like this, thanks a lot!